# Execution failed on sql ' SELECT * FROM Reviews WHERE Score != 3 LIMIT 5000': no such table: Reviews

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I need a help with the below issue i am facing:

I am trying to connect to sqllite and trying to read the data using read sql query from pandas and i am stuck with the error.

Execution failed on sql ' SELECT * FROM Reviews WHERE Score != 3 LIMIT 5000': no such table: Reviews

Below is the code snippet for accessing the sqllite and connection:

```
 con = sqlite3.connect('database.sqlite') 
print(con)
import os
os.getcwd()
os.listdir()
```

output of above code: You will see the reviews.csv file in the directory.

```
 <sqlite3.Connection object at 0x00000240C2C6C570>
['.ipynb_checkpoints',
 '03 Amazon Fine Food Reviews Analysis_KNN.ipynb',
 'Assignment_SAMPLE_SOLUTION.ipynb',
 'database.sqlite',
 'K NN Implementation with Sample Data for regression and classification.ipynb',
 'Reviews.csv']
```

Now as the file is in the directory i use this :

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

con = sqlite3.connect('database.sqlite') 
filtered_data = pd.read_sql_query(""" SELECT * FROM Reviews WHERE Score != 3 LIMIT 5000""", con)
```

the above snippet of code gives the error:

Execution failed on sql ' SELECT * FROM Reviews WHERE Score != 3 LIMIT 5000': no such table: Reviews

can you please anyone let me know where i am going wrong.

Comment: Looks like there's no table by the name `Reviews` in your database.

Comment: @MayankPorwal: How do i resolve it? I was just now sure how to do it. 

If you see the current working directory has the reviews.csv file. 

So why the read_sql_query is not able to read it ?

Answer (score 1):

The error message you get is explicit: there is no table `Reviews` in your database `'database.sqlite'`.
The `.csv` file you mention is just a csv file, and you can run sql queries only on databases by definition.

In order to know what are the available tables in the database, go to your sqllite command line by entering something like `sqlite3 database.sqlite` and use the command `.tables`. This will give you the list of tables in this database.

if you want to learn more about sqlite you can use [sqlitetutorial.net](https://sqlitetutorial.net) for example.

Comment: Nice answer. Would suggest mentioning `read_csv()` too.

Answer (score 0):

give actual location of sql dataset and still if it dont work then put r'location'.

Comment: Please wait until you have the necessary reputation to comment on a post instead of posting a comment disguised as an answer

Answer (score 0):

As Bluexm said that there is no table available called review.

I was using colab I follwed below steps and it worked for me. may be you can try these steps.

1. Generate Json api key from your kaggle profile i.e(Account-> Generate Api Key)
2. Upload the same Json file in "/root/.kaggle/"  folder
3. Download the dataset using api key
   eg.

   ```
    !kaggle datasets download -d snap/amazon-fine-food-reviews
    !unzip archive
   ```
4. ```
     con = sqlite3.connect('/content/database.sqlite') 
     filtered_data = pd.read_sql_query(""" SELECT * FROM Reviews WHERE Score != 3 LIMIT 5000""", con)
   ```